# section functor with support in a point of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

Let $Z$ be a locally closed subset of a topological space, one denote classically by $\Gamma_{Z}$ the functor of section with support.
Let $x$ be a point of the affine space $\mathbb{R}^n$, we denote by $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ the constant sheaf on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that we can describe $R\Gamma_{\{x\}}\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ by $\mathbb{R}_{\{x\}}[-n]$ (obviously this should be valid for a general constant sheaf of $A$-module on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for a ring $A$).

Using the triangle $R\Gamma_{\{x\}}\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rightarrow R\Gamma_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rightarrow R\Gamma_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x\}}\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\xrightarrow{+1}$, we get immediately that $R\Gamma_{\{x\}}\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is concentrated in degree $n$ and the $H^{n}$ is isomorphic to the $H^{n-1}(R\Gamma_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x\}})$  which is for me $\mathbb{R}_{\{x\}}$. Are we OK ?

Comment: I don't see why you said it is concentrated in degree 2, in fact it is concentrated in degree $n$ since $R\Gamma_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x\}}(A)=A[0]\oplus A[-n+1]$ and so $R\Gamma_{x}(A)=A[-n]$ for any constant sheaf $A$.

Comment: @Roland oups sorry, I wrote it initially for $n=2$ I updated it !

Comment: btw @Roland are you sure it is not $A_{\{x\}}[-n]$ ?

Comment: Oh by $\Gamma_Z(A)$ you mean the sheaf $U\mapsto\Gamma_Z(U,A)$ ? I thought you meant only its global sections $\Gamma_Z(X,A)$. So, yes in the sheaffy case you are right of course.

Comment: Btw, in your edit, you put $H^{n-1}$ is isomorphic to the $H^{n-2}(R\Gamma_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{x\}})$, but the degrees are $n$ and $n-1$.

Comment: @Roland exactly that's what I meant the sheaf and not the global sections. Btw, thank you for your vigilance, indeed of course ;)